# Sign Up via Graph API and verify if user is in control of email and phone number

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I know it's possible to create Azure B2C users via Graph API.
But is it also possible to trigger the email verification? And the phone verification? All from APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible but nothing stops you from creating your own verification logic. You would disable the user account while verification is pending and enable it once it's done. [All trough MS Graph.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)